# Selenium unable to locate pop-up banner button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, bots

I'm trying to scrape the names, prices etc. of the vehicles on this website. Since the site only loads 12 cars at the start, i have to press the "show more vehicles" button(Daha fazla otomobil göster). However, since there is a cookie pop-up that occupies the screen at that moment, i have to close it using one of the buttons on it - i preferred to click on only accept necessary cookies(Yalnızca gerekli çerezleri kabul et). When i try to close it as follows, i get an error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
import time

def close_banner(browser):
    browser.find_element_by_class_name('button--only-technically-necessary').click()

url = "https://shop.mercedes-benz.com/tr-tr/shop/vehicle/srp/used?sort=relevance&assortment=vehicle"

opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

opt.add_argument('--start-maximized')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt)

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/button')
while True:
    try:
        btn.click()
        break
    except selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException:
        close_banner(driver)
```

The html for the buttons are as follows:
Cookie banner button:

```
<wb7-button class="button button--only-technically-necessary wb-button hydrated" data-test="handle-deny-button" variant="primary" size="s" theme="light">Yalnızca zorunlu çerezleri kabul et</wb7-button>
```

[Couldn't copy its children on Chrome:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kieh.png)

Show more button:

```
<button data-test-id="dcp-result-pagination__load-more" class="dcp-result-pagination__load-more wb-button wb-button--secondary wb-button--large"> Daha fazla otomobil göster </button>
```

And the error I get is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button data-test-id="dcp-result-pagination__load-more" class="dcp-result-pagination__load-more wb-button wb-button--secondary wb-button--large">...</button> is not clickable at point (1176, 879). Other element would receive the click: <cmm-cookie-banner settings-id="lNUr7ZitD" variant="A" labels="{&quot;showDetails&quot;: &quot;Show details&quot;, &quot;hideDetails&quot;: &quot;Hide details&quot;}" class="hydrated"></cmm-cookie-banner>

...

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".button--only-technically-necessary"}
```

There were some posts on this issue; however, none seemed to solve my problem. What am i doing wrong in my code?

I also tried to use different identifiers, class name, link text, css selector etc., but none seemed to change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The close_banner function is not being executed because it is trying to click an element which is under the shadow-root. In your case, change the code as below and you will be able to click the pop up

Accessing shadow DOM elements with Javascript

```
def close_banner(browser):
popup_btn = browser.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('#cmm_bookie_banner cmm-cookie-banner ').shadowRoot.querySelector('.button--only-technically-necessary')""")
popup_btn.click()
```

Accessing shadow DOM elements with Selenium 4

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
def close_banner(browser):
shadow_host = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#cmm_bookie_banner cmm-cookie-banner')
shadow_root = shadow_host.shadow_root
popup_button = shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.button--only-technically-necessary')
popup_button.click()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked perfectly. However, i wonder if there is a way to do this using the class, id etc.

Comment: I know 2 ways to access Shadow DOM elements. one with javascript and two with Selenium 4 (Chromium browsers version 96 or greater). I added the selenium version to the answer